# If every field backing the props of a VM implement INotifyPropChange does the VM need to implement INotifyPropChagned?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

If my model implements INotifyPropertyChanged and does my VM need to?

Clarification: In the real case where you have SomeOtherProp then INotifyPropertyChanged absolutely needs to be implemented.  What I am really after is how much work I have to do (replicate) for well formed models.

Example:

```
namespace Question
{
    public interface IFoo : INotifyPropertyChanged { }
    public interface IBar : INotifyPropertyChanged { }

    public interface IModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        IFoo Foo { get; set; }
        ObservableCollection<IBar> BarCollection { get; }
    }

    public class VM : TypeSafeViewModelBase
    //Clarification: added VM base clase with typesafe override for RaisePropertyChanged
    {
        private IModel _model;
        public VM( IModel model )
        {
            this._model = model;
            //Clarification: added this call...
            this._model.PropertyChanged += ( sender, args ) => base.RaisePropertyChanged(args.PropertyName);
            //That is the one I have questions about and ultimateley what I  want to avoid
        }

        public IFoo Foo { get { return this._model.Foo; } }
        public ObservableCollection<IBar> BarCollection { get { return this._model.BarCollection; } }

        //clarification: added this prop declaration
        //I know this would be needed as this property is backed by a private member of this class
        private string _someOtherProp;
        public string SomeOtherProp
        {
            get { return this._someOtherProp; }
            set
            {
                this._someOtherProp = value;
                base.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.SomeOtherProp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does VM need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged?  And relay all the events to the V?  Or do things in the V bind to lowest level objects which implement the PropertyChanged and CollectionChanged interfaces?

I can't seem to find a definitive answer for how much glue code I need to write if I have a well formed, notifying model layer...

PS. I am developing in SL4 using Prism and Ninject if that matters.  My model is mutable, stateful, and in local memory (I keep a local cache because hitting the server after every operation is not practical).

Comment: I'd argue that you don't have any view state in that ViewModel and your model uses the INotifyXXX mechanism, then you don't need the 'ViewModel' as it isn't really a ViewModel at all.

Comment: @RitchMelton, Agreed, My example was overly simple.  See the clarified example.  VM now has state (e.g. think IsVisible, InitialPosition or something similar).  My production VMs keep track of V state and the middle layer is warranted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you don't need to implement interface itself in your case. For example, VM doesn't need to implement `INotifyPropertyChange` if you use RIA services business object since those already do implement it.

However! Most likely you still want to do that because properties like "IsBusy", "CanSave" and so on usually belong to VM itself and then you need interface.

Usually every application have some type of `VMBase` object that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, `INotifyDataErrorInfo` and so on. And every VM inherits from this base class

Comment: Good points.  I have clarified the example to be more representative of the production code.  I am using a base class that extends ViewModelBase in MVVMLight.

Comment: MVVMLight and all other MVVM frameworks implement INotifyPropertyChanged as a minimum what they do :) So, you good. No need to implement it - you already got it via MVVMLight

Answer (score 1):

There is a penalty for implementing and maintaining any abstraction and in the case of MVVM, there's quite a bit of glue code that is unavoidable. The question to ask is not if the glue code is appropriate, but is the abstraction itself appropriate? Do you have reuse in your viewmodels? Are you making heavy use of databinding? Is unit testing your viewmodels something that your team does? or is integration testing your viewmodels a part of your development cycle?

To answer your question specifically, in your design, the model is doing some of the work for the viewmodel by implementing INotifyPropertyChanged and providing observable collections. I like to implement my models by using as much of the base language and libraries as possible. This means my collections would be generic lists, hashsets, etc..., and my eventing mechanism would involve custom events and delegates (implemented as an event aggregator).

My viewmodel ends up doing more wrapping and adapting to the view, but neither approach is bad.